# Binary digits: what does '-0b1' represent?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, bit-manipulation

I am trying to find out the bit manipulation in the background of the following code:

```
   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       break
```

when I type in bin(cv2.waitKey(1)) I get '-0b1' as the output

Comment: Is that a `-0b1` or `~0b1`?

Answer (score 2):

It's negative one in binary without the 2s complement representation.  Python integers are not limited as in other languages.  A 32-bit negative one in 2s complement would be 0xFFFFFFFF or 0b11111111111111111111111111111111, but you can't write an infinite number of ones, so `-0b1` is the shortcut.

Comment: `bin(-1)` for quick proof